# Getting permission denied with key pair generated by terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I wrote terraform script create a new key pair that is attached to the new instance

But I am getting permission denied

```
data "aws_ami" "latest-amazon-linux-image" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["amazon"]
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-gp2"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "ssh-key" {
  key_name   = "server-key"
  public_key = file(var.public_key_location)

}
resource "aws_instance" "myapp-server" {
  ami               = data.aws_ami.latest-amazon-linux-image.id
  instance_type     = var.instance_type
  subnet_id         = aws_subnet.dev-subnet-1.id
  security_groups   = [aws_default_security_group.myapp-sg.id]
  availability_zone = var.avail_zone
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = aws_key_pair.ssh-key.key_name
  tags = {
    Name : "${var.env_prefix}-server"
  }
}
output "ec2_public_ip" {
  value =  aws_instance.myapp-server.public_ip
}
```

login into the instance with the key with the following command

```
ssh -i key-path ec2-user@public-ip
```

error

```
ec2-user@18.218.179.236: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Probably you are using incorrect `var.public_key_location` or `-i key-path`. Sadly no one here can help you with that, as only use can verify correctness of these keys.